# Umbraco culture and hostnames affects validation

Tags: validation, umbraco, umbraco7, hostname, culture

I've got very wired problem. I have payment page on which I've got amount with custom model. Here is validation for that property:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Kwota - Pole wymagane!")]
    [Display(Name = "Kwota: ")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$", ErrorMessage = "Proszę podać poprawną kwotę!")]
    [Range(00.01, 99999999999, ErrorMessage = "Kwota musi być większa niż 0.00")]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
```

I'm trying to make site in multiple languages so I follow standard umbraco process but once I change language or hostname the above property return:

"The value '1.00' is not valid for Kwota: ."

This doesn't fail if my culture language is inherit and there is no domains added but once I add domain or change culture language it fails. Any idea or reason?

I have checked and it happens on server side as I can hit breakpoint on post action.
I have also noticed that once I change culture and hostnames I'm no longer hitting breakpoint on my custom validation for honeypot witch is on model - I just simply implement IValidatableObject.

Just to clarify I'm running: Umbraco version 7.4.3 assembly: 1.0.5948.18141

Any help very appreciated.

Comment: I wonder if validation finds a specific model with properties for English sites. Checkout this SO post about globalisation and custom models: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383761/umbraco-culture-and-hostnames-affects-validation. There's also an interesting article here: http://haacked.com/archive/2010/05/10/globalizing-mvc-validation.aspx/

Comment: Hey thanks for reply unfortunately 1st link goes to my question and 2nd is about client validation while my problem happens on server side. Any other ideas?